# unable to install Tidyverse in RStudio / Chromebook

Tags: r, tidyverse, chromebook

I have been trying to install tidyverse via RStudio (R 4.3.1) on my Acer chromebook, but keep having error messages.
I have been working my way through these messages with the help of previously asked questions on stackoverflow as well as google and chatGPT
I have tried various things and have managed to install some of the missing dependencies, but got stuck with the latest one. It's been several hours since I tried to dowload it, and I am not out of ideas as I feel I tried everything that I could find.

I am not unable to get the dependent package ragg installed, or any of the other bits like libtiff-4, as per the error message.

I tried to install tidyverse in R - through studio as well as:
`install.packages("tidyverse")`

I then got the following message from R:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/nicoledigruber26/R/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘ragg’
```

```
trying URL '[https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ragg_1.2.6.tar.gz](https://stackoverflow.com)'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 425391 bytes (415 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 415 KB

trying URL '[https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidyverse_2.0.0.tar.gz](https://stackoverflow.com)'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 704618 bytes (688 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 688 KB
```

```
installing *source* package ‘ragg’ ...
** package ‘ragg’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libtiff-4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libtiff-4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'libtiff-4', required by 'virtual:world', not found
Package libtiff-4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libtiff-4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'libtiff-4', required by 'virtual:world', not found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lfreetype -lpng16 -ltiff -lz -ljpeg -lbz2

-----------------------------[ ANTICONF ]-------------------------------
Configuration failed to find one of freetype2 libpng libtiff-4 libjpeg. Try installing:
 * deb: libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: freetype-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel libjpeg-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libfreetype_dev libpng16_dev libtiff_dev libjpeg_dev (Solaris)
If freetype2 libpng libtiff-4 libjpeg is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a freetype2 libpng libtiff-4 libjpeg.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
-------------------------- [ERROR MESSAGE] ---------------------------
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ragg’
* removing ‘/home/nicoledigruber26/R/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/4.3/ragg’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ragg’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ragg’ is not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/nicoledigruber26/R/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/4.3/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpOXWUgy/downloaded_packages’
```

I run an update and an upgrade in the linux terminal
`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt upgrade`

and then I tried to install the version it is asking for
`sudo apt install libfreetype-dev=2.13.0+dfsg-1`

but got the following message:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libfreetype-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Version '2.13.0+dfsg-1' for 'libfreetype-dev' was not found

I then checked to see
`apt list -a libfreetype-dev`

and this is what I got: 
libfreetype-dev/unstable,now 2.13.2+dfsg-1 arm64 [installed] 
libfreetype-dev/oldstable 2.10.4+dfsg-1+deb11u1 arm64

I went to a different part of the R message to see if there is more I could do and
I tried to install libtiff-4, but also got an error

```
sudo apt install libtiff-4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libtiff-4
```

tried again using:

```
sudo apt install libtiff-4-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libtiff-4-dev
```

Thanks in advance for your help,
I hope I have entered enough information.